# unable to percolate : org.elasticsearch.index.percolator.PercolatorException: [myindex] failed to parse query [myDesignatedQueryName]

Tags: scala, elasticsearch, scala-2.11, elasticsearch-percolate

I am following [this guide](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-api/current/percolate.html) and converting this percolate api java code in scala but when i run this  in SBT it throws following exceptions

```
[error] (run-main-0) org.elasticsearch.index.percolator.PercolatorException: [myindex] failed to parse query [myDesignatedQueryName]
org.elasticsearch.index.percolator.PercolatorException: [myindex] failed to parse query [myDesignatedQueryName]
    at org.elasticsearch.index.percolator.PercolatorQueriesRegistry.parsePercolatorDocument(PercolatorQueriesRegistry.java:194)
    at org.elasticsearch.index.percolator.PercolatorQueriesRegistry$RealTimePercolatorOperationListener.preIndex(PercolatorQueriesRegistry.java:309)
    at org.elasticsearch.index.indexing.ShardIndexingService.preIndex(ShardIndexingService.java:139)
    at org.elasticsearch.index.shard.service.InternalIndexShard.index(InternalIndexShard.java:420)
    at org.elasticsearch.action.index.TransportIndexAction.shardOperationOnPrimary(TransportIndexAction.java:193)
    at org.elasticsearch.action.support.replication.TransportShardReplicationOperationAction$AsyncShardOperationAction.performOnPrimary(TransportShardReplicationOperationAction.java:511)
    at org.elasticsearch.action.support.replication.TransportShardReplicationOperationAction$AsyncShardOperationAction$1.run(TransportShardReplicationOperationAction.java:419)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.elasticsearch.index.query.QueryParsingException: [myindex] Strict field resolution and no field mapping can be found for the field with name [content]
    at org.elasticsearch.index.query.QueryParseContext.failIfFieldMappingNotFound(QueryParseContext.java:393)
    at org.elasticsearch.index.query.QueryParseContext.smartFieldMappers(QueryParseContext.java:372)
    at org.elasticsearch.index.query.TermQueryParser.parse(TermQueryParser.java:95)
    at org.elasticsearch.index.query.QueryParseContext.parseInnerQuery(QueryParseContext.java:277)
    at org.elasticsearch.index.query.IndexQueryParserService.parseInnerQuery(IndexQueryParserService.java:321)
    at org.elasticsearch.index.percolator.PercolatorQueriesRegistry.parseQuery(PercolatorQueriesRegistry.java:207)
    at org.elasticsearch.index.percolator.PercolatorQueriesRegistry.parsePercolatorDocument(PercolatorQueriesRegistry.java:191)
    at org.elasticsearch.index.percolator.PercolatorQueriesRegistry$RealTimePercolatorOperationListener.preIndex(PercolatorQueriesRegistry.java:309)
    at org.elasticsearch.index.indexing.ShardIndexingService.preIndex(ShardIndexingService.java:139)
    at org.elasticsearch.index.shard.service.InternalIndexShard.index(InternalIndexShard.java:420)
    at org.elasticsearch.action.index.TransportIndexAction.shardOperationOnPrimary(TransportIndexAction.java:193)
    at org.elasticsearch.action.support.replication.TransportShardReplicationOperationAction$AsyncShardOperationAction.performOnPrimary(TransportShardReplicationOperationAction.java:511)
    at org.elasticsearch.action.support.replication.TransportShardReplicationOperationAction$AsyncShardOperationAction$1.run(TransportShardReplicationOperationAction.java:419)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
[trace] Stack trace suppressed: run last compile:run for the full output.
```

here is my code

```
object PercolateApiES extends App{
  val node =nodeBuilder().client(true).node()
val client =node.client()

  val qb=QueryBuilders.termQuery("content","amazing")

val res=client.prepareIndex("myindex", ".percolator", "myDesignatedQueryName")
    .setSource(jsonBuilder()
        .startObject()
            .field("query", qb) // Register the query
        .endObject())
    .setRefresh(true) // Needed when the query shall be available immediately
    .execute().actionGet();
val docBuilder = XContentFactory.jsonBuilder().startObject();
docBuilder.field("doc").startObject(); //This is needed to designate the document
docBuilder.field("content", "This is amazing!");
docBuilder.endObject(); //End of the doc field
docBuilder.endObject(); //End of the JSON root object
//Percolate
val response = client.preparePercolate()
                        .setIndices("myindex")
                        .setDocumentType("myDocumentType")
                        .setSource(docBuilder).execute().actionGet();
node.close
}
```

When I write these commands using curl they work fine

```
curl -XPUT 'localhost:9200/myindex1' -d '{
  "mappings": {
    "mytype": {
      "properties": {
        "content": {
          "type": "string"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}'

{"acknowledged":true}

curl -XPUT 'localhost:9200/myindex1/.percolator/myDesignatedQueryName' -d '{
    "query" : {
        "term" : {
            "content" : "amazing"
        }
    }
}'


{"_index":"myindex1","_type":".percolator","_id":"myDesignatedQueryName","_version":1,"created":true}

curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/myindex1/content/_percolate' -d '{
    "doc" : {
        "content" : "This is amazing!"
    }
}'

{"took":231,"_shards":{"total":5,"successful":5,"failed":0},"total":1,"matches":[{"_index":"myindex1","_id":"myDesignatedQueryName"}]}
```

I am using elastic search-1.4.1 Please help me where i am making mistake and also i want to seethe results asi dont know how to do this in code

```
matches":[{"_index":"myindex1","_id":"myDesignatedQueryName"}
```

How can I fetch the result ,please help me and guide me ,Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ES 1.4.0.Beta1 has introduced a breaking change which affects the percolator API. Basically, we need to set the `index.query.parse.allow_unmapped_fields` explicitly to `true`. Refer to http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-dynamic-mapping.html#_unmapped_fields_in_queries for details.

The actual conversation on adding this change is in their Github https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/issues/6664.

Here is another related issue: [index.query.parse.allow_unmapped_fields setting does not seem to allow unmapped fields in alias filters](https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/issues/8431)